# MLE estimator of $\theta$ for $f(x;\theta)=e^{i\theta -Xi}$

Tags: statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

$X_1...X_i$ are independent randomly distributed with pdf $$f(x_i|\theta)=e^{i\theta-x_i}$$$ 
$$x_i≥i\theta$

-Previous problems I had done where the range of x was dependent on $\theta$ just involved bounds ....$x_i\lt\theta$ than you just use $X_n$ and when $x_i\gt\theta$, I use $X_1$. I was just confused because this time the bounds are $i\theta$.

- My thoughts were to just use $X_1/i$ as the MLE of $\theta$ but I was not sure

Comment: note that $i\theta-x_i$ should all be in the exponent I just had some issues with the math jax

Comment: If the bounds depends on $i$, then the random variables $X_1,\dots, X_i$ are not iid.

Comment: fixed sorry mixed up part of a previous problem with this one....now shows they are just independent randomly distributed

Answer (score 1):

The joint probabilty of the $X_s$'s is: $$f(x_1, \ldots, x_i | \theta) = e^{\sum_{s=1}^i (s\theta -x_s)}1_{\{\min_s\{x_s/s \} \ge \theta\}}$$

This is because: $$ \Pi_{s = 1}^i 1_{\{x_s \ge s \theta\}} = 1_{\{\min_s\{x_s/s \} \ge \theta\}}$$

Finding MLE means finding the argument $\theta$ that maximises this function. Hence we ask:

- $\theta \le \min_s\{x_s/s\}$

Since the exponential function is strictly increasing in $\theta,$ we find that the argument that maximises the distribution is exactly:

$$\theta: = \min_s\{x_s/s\}$$

Comment: so I was right in thinking that it would just be $X_1/i$ where $X_1$ is the minimum order statistic?

Comment: Ah, yes sorry. I didn't understand that you ment the minimum order statistic. You were totally right (in my opinion).

Comment: woot! this was a sample problem from a previous test by a teacher and I was kinda freaking out if it wasnt

Comment: @Cornelis Your answer is OK, but it is not the same as $X_1/i$.

Comment: Yes, you are right Byron, got confused by notation. Anyhow $X_1$ is an ambiguous notation: it shouldn't be used to represent an order statistic. What is needed is clearly the minimum order statistic of the $X_s/s.$

Comment: sounds good to me...I appreciate the assistance and will endeavor to use more clear notation in the future :D